# Pass and retrieve AJAX data to controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have this code in my view **Index.cshtml**:

```
<script>
    var dropdown = $('#clientDropdown');
    dropdown.on('change', function () {
        var clients = dropdown.chosen().val();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/Inventory/GetClient',
            datatype: 'json',
            data: {clients : clients},
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

What it does is it sends an array object named **clients (var clients)**  to my controller. For example, it passes an array object of **["Chan","John"]**

Now in my controller, this is my code:

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult GetClient()
    {
        var clients = Request.QueryString["clients"];

        return Json(new { data = clients }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

After the AJAX call, the controller returns a *{data:null}* object in the console log. What am I missing? I wanted to use the content of my **clients** object in my controller for returning a JSON data

Comment: have you tried debugging the runtime value of `clients` in your c# code?

Comment: @garryman yup. it's not even fetching the data from the ajax call

Comment: check my updated answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must send a string version of `JSON`, here's some changes you should make

```
var dropdown = $('#clientDropdown');
    dropdown.on('change', function () {
        var clients = dropdown.chosen().val();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/Inventory/GetClient',
            contentType: 'application/json', // this
            datatype: 'json',
            data: {clients : JSON.stringify(clients)}, // and this
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: oh wait. i wanted to retrieve it as an object. when I log data.data[0], is outputs "["

Comment: console.log(JSON.parse(data)[0]);